# R - appended columns from different tables

Tags: r

I have 10 tables (2 columns) which share a common column (second column) and the first columns of each table holds information for years 2000-2010. Like this

Table1

```
Amount2000    Percentage
3             80-100
9             60-80
14            40-60
9             20-40
0             0-20
```

Table2

```
Amount2001    Percentage
3             80-100
9             60-80
14            40-60
9             20-40
0             0-20
```

etc.

What I want to do is create a table like the following:

```
Percentage   Amount2000  Amount2001   Amount2002.......
.
.
.
```

by using cbind perhaps? What is the best way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `merge(Table1,Table2)` in a loop for merging Table1-10. If each Percentage sections has the same length and are in the same order try `cbind(Table1[,2:1],Table2[,1],Table2[,1],...)`.

Comment: the cbind method works well. my only complaint would be that the third column onwards uses Amount20012001[,1] and so on as the column headers. This can be solved by changing Table2[,1] to Table[0:1].